# Meteor Mongo Accessing list of IDs from another collection for Meteor.publish

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have **Rooms** and **Messages** collections in addition to my **Meteor.users** collection.

As part of the **Rooms** schema, there is a *userId* (string): this references the **Meteor.user** that started the room. **Meteor.users** only have access to rooms they started.

As part of the **Messages** schema, there is a *userId* (string) and *roomId* (string): these are the **Meteor.user** that posted the message and the **Room** to which it was posted.

Now, I only want my **Meteor.users** to be able to subscribe to **Messages** that have been posted to the rooms that they have access. So, this includes messages to their rooms from other users. The code below only subscribes to user's messages, not all messages to their rooms.

How would I go about doing this?

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function() {
  return Messages.find({userId: this.userId});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're saying is that you want to retrieve all the **Messages** from any **Rooms** the **current user** started.  I think this should solve it:

```
Meteor.publish("messages.allForCurrentUser", function() {
    var currentUser = this.userId;
    var roomsForCurrentUser = Rooms.find({ userId: currentUser }).fetch().map(function(room) { 
        return room._id;
    });  // Gets an array of all Room IDs for the user.
    return Messages.find({ roomId: { $in: roomsForCurrentUser } });
});
```

I first grab the current user, then use that to find all rooms the user started.  Next, the .map allows me to translate from an array of objects [{ _id: 'blah'}, ...] to an array of string internal ids ['blah', ...].  Then I use MongoDB $in to get all messages with a room id in that array of room ids.  I didn't do anything with user id since it looks like a message in a room could be from any user id.

Comment: Thanks! Works great.